# Set controller property inside callback

Tags: ember.js

I have the following controller using `ember.js` and the [`ember-auth`](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth) gem. This controller works but it sets the `loginError`property each time I get a sign in.

```
BaseApp.SignInController = Auth.SignInController.extend({
  email: null,
  password: null,
  loginError: false,
  signIn: function() {
    this.registerRedirect();
    Auth.signIn({
      email: this.get('email'),
      password: this.get('password')
    });
    this.set('loginError', true); // Sets correctly but each time
    Auth.on('signInError', function() {
      console.log("This is a signin error");
    });
  }
});
```

Obviously what I would like to do is set `loginError` to `true` inside the function that is called by `Auth.on` like this:

```
BaseApp.SignInController = Auth.SignInController.extend({
  email: null,
  password: null,
  loginError: false,
  signIn: function() {
    this.registerRedirect();
    Auth.signIn({
      email: this.get('email'),
      password: this.get('password')
    });
    Auth.on('signInError', function() {
      this.set('loginError', true); // Doesn't set the controller's property
      console.log("This is a signin error");
    });
  }
});
```

But this obviously doesn't work because the scope inside the callback is different. Maybe I'm missing something very basic. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context (ie. `this`) is different within the anonymous function you pass to the `on` method than in the controller. You can get around this by saving the context to a different variable within the closure.

```
var self = this;
Auth.on('signInError', function() {
  self.set('loginError', true); // Should now set the controller's property
  console.log("This is a signin error");
});
```

Comment: You can also use [.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), (for IE it requires IE9)